# Getting Self_Reference_From_Trigger Error on my New SF Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error, delete

Trying to delete a record on the ContentDocument Object based on a ContentDocumentLink Trigger.  Everything is setup correctly but I get the Self_Reference_From_Trigger error.  I am thinking that it is because I have it setup as a Before Delete but when I change it to After Delete it doesn't work either.  Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

TRIGGER:

```
trigger Update_Image_Field_BPR2 on ContentDocumentLink (after insert, after update, before delete, after undelete){
try{
    List<Subject__c> subList = new List<Subject__c>();
    List<Business__c> busList = new List<Business__c>();
    List<ContentDocument> docList = new List<ContentDocument>();
    List<Schema.SobjectField> imageFldBus = new List<Schema.SobjectField> {
        Business__c.Image1__c,
        Business__c.Image2__c,
        Business__c.Image3__c,
        Business__c.Image4__c,
        Business__c.Image5__c};
    List<Schema.SobjectField> imageFldSubs = new List<Schema.SobjectField> {
        Subject__c.Image1__c,
        Subject__c.Image2__c,
        Subject__c.Image3__c,
        Subject__c.Image4__c,
        Subject__c.Image5__c};
    //Set of Subject__c Ids that we will iterate through
    Set<id> fileIds = new Set<id>();
    Set<id> contentIds = new Set<id>();
    String deleteFile = null;
    for(ContentDocumentLink content : Trigger.IsDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new){
        Id parentObjId = content.LinkedEntityId;
        if(parentObjId.getSObjectType() == Subject__c.SObjectType || parentObjId.getSObjectType() == Business__c.SObjectType){
            fileIds.add(content.LinkedEntityId);
            contentIds.add(content.ContentDocumentId);
        }        
    }
    // Get the Subject__c id and Image1__c  for each Subject__c
    Map<id, Subject__c> subMap = new Map<id, Subject__c>([Select id, Image1__c, Image2__c, Image3__c, Image4__c, Image5__c 
                                                          from Subject__c Where Id in :fileIds]);  
    Map<id, Business__c> busMap = new Map<id, Business__c>([Select id, Image1__c, Image2__c, Image3__c, Image4__c, Image5__c 
                                                            from Business__c Where Id in :fileIds]);  
    Map<id, ContentDocumentLink> docMap = new Map<id, ContentDocumentLink>([SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId 
                                                                            FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :fileIds
                                                                           AND (ContentDocument.FileExtension = 'jpg' OR ContentDocument.FileExtension = 'jpeg' 
                                                                                OR ContentDocument.FileExtension = 'png' OR ContentDocument.FileExtension = 'gif')]); 
    Map<id, ContentDocument> contentMap = new Map<id, ContentDocument>([SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :contentIds]);
    for(ContentDocumentLink content : Trigger.IsDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new){
        Id parentObjId = content.LinkedEntityId;
        ContentDocument doc = contentMap.get(content.contentdocumentid);
        docList.add(doc);
        if(parentObjId.getSObjectType() == Business__c.SObjectType){
            Business__c bus = busMap.get(content.LinkedEntityId);
            ContentDocumentLink querymember = docMap.get(content.id);
            String fullFileURL = querymember.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId;
            system.debug(fullFileURL);
            if(!Trigger.IsDelete){
                for (Schema.SobjectField f : imageFldbus)
                if (bus.get(f) == null) { // is curr val null?
                    bus.put(f,fullFileUrl);  // set null val to url and leave loop
                    break;
                }}
            if(Trigger.IsDelete){
                for (Schema.SobjectField f : imageFldbus)
                if (bus.get(f) == fullFileUrl) { // is curr val URL?
                    bus.put(f,null);  // set val to null and leave loop
                    deleteFile = '1';
                    break;
                }}
            busList.add(bus);
        }
        if(parentObjId.getSObjectType() == Subject__c.SObjectType){
            Subject__c sub = subMap.get(content.LinkedEntityId);
            ContentDocumentLink querymember = docMap.get(content.id);
            String fullFileURL = querymember.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId;
            system.debug(fullFileURL);
            if(!Trigger.IsDelete){
                for (Schema.SobjectField f : imageFldsubs)
                if (sub.get(f) == null) { // is curr val null?
                    sub.put(f,fullFileUrl);  // set null val to url and leave loop
                    break;
                }}
            if(Trigger.IsDelete){
                for (Schema.SobjectField f : imageFldsubs)
                if (sub.get(f) == fullFileUrl) { // is curr val URL?
                    sub.put(f,null);  // set val to null and leave loop
                    deleteFile = '1';
                    break;
                }}            
            subList.add(sub);          
        }
    }
    if(subList != null && subList.size() > 0){update subList;}
    if(busList != null && busList.size() > 0){update busList;}
    if(deleteFile != null){delete docList;}
} catch(Exception e){ System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);}
}
```

Comment: Wrapping all of your logic in a `try`/`catch` block is a truly terrible idea. Especially when you only catch a general `Exception` and also especially when you only debug said exception.

Comment: What's the nature of the relationship between ContentDocumentLink and ContentDocument ? Master-Detail ?

Comment: I believe it is a master detail.  It is a standard object that SF uses for Files.  Check this link out for more details: [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content)

Comment: In the UI, are you trying to delete the ContentDocument first or ContentDocumentLink ?

Comment: In the UI the trigger is fired after the deletion of the ContentDocumentLink.  I just want to delete the underlying ContentDocument record as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid this by using a future method.

```
@future
public static void deleteContentDocuments(Set<Id> ids)
{
    Database.delete(new List<Id>(ids));
}
```

From your trigger, you will perform something like:

```
Set<Id> toDelete = new Set<Id>();
List<ContentDocumentLink> records = trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new;
for (ContentDocumentLink link : records)
    toDelete.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
deleteContentDocuments(toDelete);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem of order of execution. When you delete ContentDocumentLink, you want to delete the underlying ContentDocument, which is fine. But because of the nature of the relationship, Master-Details(MD). When you delete ContentDocument in your trigger, it will try to delete all children linked by a MD, that means your ContentDocumentLink itself. --> Self_Reference_From_Trigger error